# How to represent <T> using alias like typedef for function in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my code where there are multiple streambuilders of type `<Uint8List, GlobalKey<ObjectState>>` and it always makes editor refactor it to multiline which is making the code harder to read. Is there any way to shorten it like typedef for function or any way I can make it a bit neater without changing editor rules?
Upon looking for solutions I stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/65) issue on dart sdk. Has there been any development on it since then?

Comment: Typedefs are only for functions.  You might be able to use `<Uint8List, GlobalKey<ObjectState>> Function ([parameters])`.

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue. I am looking for alias for type itself. 
On the issue I mentioned, there is a development going on with the syntax `typedef foo=Map<int,String>` but it hasn't been implemented in dart it seems.

Comment: At the moment, typedef is only for Function-derived types.